# What are the dimensions of a Trek Marlin 7 rear wheel quick release skewer?

Tags: repair, parts, replacement, quick-release, trek

My Trek Marlin 7 is size large and has 29-inch wheels. I want to replace the broken quick release skewer of the rear wheel and I need help finding a suitable replacement.

Answer (score 5):

It's just a standard QR skewer for 135mm rear ends. Your local bike shop or favorite online retailer should have them readily available for $20 or so. They're more or less a standard length.